# How to download all files from directory using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework for a website. I need to download all the files from a particular directory. I can do this task using PHP alone but not working in codeigniter may be due to some path issue. I searched on many sites but not able to get correct solution. Also, followed official documentation here : [codeigniter zip documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/zip.html) , but without any success. I need working code , which can be tested directly.
code which I have now is :

```
$path = '/path/to/your/directory/';

$this->zip->read_dir($path);

// Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

Comment: Does anyone knows the answer ? I stuck at this point .

Comment: Do you want download zip file from a folder

Comment: @KumarRakesh I want to download entire folder.

Comment: Try without slash at the begining: `path/to/your/directory`, in case `path` folder in your document root (relative to index.php)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tries, finally i found the exact problem. Actually, the CodeIgniter code works perfectly. The problem is setting the path. Here I am zipping a folder named noimg inside assets folder inside CodeIgniter project folder.

```
  function zip()
{
    $this->load->library('zip');

    $path = FCPATH.'/assets/noimg';

    $this->zip->read_dir($path,FALSE);

    // Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
    $this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
}
```

Don't forget to put 'FCPATH.' before /assets very important. Then only the path can be identified. If you have any problem please comment below. The above code work perfectly for me

Comment: I solved the problem. But I am able to run code without dot, why is it so? Will it give problem when actually running on live hosting instead of localhost?  Also adding base_url() to path not working , What can be the reason for it ?

Comment: Oh , shit . I just tried '.' before path and guess what instead of downloading zip of files, it was just text file without anything inside.

Comment: Did my code work for you? As you said I uploaded my project to my Debian server and try again and it works perfectly.

Comment: i edited my code by using FCPATH please try again this time